# PluginError: Package "expo-font" does not contain a valid config plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

$ npx expo start
Starting project at C:\Users\Sanjar\Desktop\FIP\vroom-vroom
PluginError: Package "expo-font" does not contain a valid config plugin.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin

Unexpected token 'export'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcZIV.png)

у меня реагирует на родной проект, сделал его на imac, там все работает нормально, прокт запускается, но на ноутбуке Windows выдает эту ошибку.
I react to my native project, I made it on imac, everything works fine there, the project starts, but on a Windows laptop it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

`expo-font`is not compatible with certain `expo sdk` versions. The current `expo sdk` version is 50. Try updating your `expo sdk`.
(You will need to anyways for it to remain compatible with Expo Go or app stores.)

**I found that `expo@50.0.7` and `expo-font@11.10.3` were compatible in my application.**

You can do this by running `npm install expo@50.0.7`

Then run `npx expo install --fix` to make sure your dependencies update with your sdk.

Then run `npm install expo-font@11.10.3` -- this should be the compatible version.